# Convergence of $\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{\left( 2\sqrt[n] {n}-1\right) ^{n}}{n^{4}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove the convergence of the following series:

$$\sum ^{\infty }_{n=1}\dfrac{\left( 2\sqrt[n] {n}-1\right) ^{n}}{n^{4}}$$
So basically I've tried:

1. Ratio test
2. Root test
3. Tried comparing for a direct comparison test with:

Bigger series:
$\sum ^{\infty }_{n=0}\dfrac{\left( 2\sqrt[n] {n}\right) ^{n}}{n^{4}}$ but it diverges.
$\sum ^{\infty }_{n=0}\dfrac{\left( 2\sqrt[n] {n}-1\right) ^{n}}{\ln \left( n\right) }$ but it diverges.

Smaller series:
$\sum ^{\infty }_{n=0}\dfrac{1}{n^{4}}$ but it converges.

I just can't seem to find a good one.
Could anyone help?

Comment: Hint: $$
2\sqrt[n]{n} - 1 = 2\exp \left( {\frac{{\log n}}{n}} \right) - 1 = 1 + 2\frac{{\log n}}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{{n^2 }}} \right)
$$ and $$
(2\sqrt[n]{n} - 1)^n  = \exp \left( {n\log \left( {1 + 2\frac{{\log n}}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)} \right) = \exp \left( {2\log n + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{n}} \right)} \right) = n^2 \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{n}} \right)} \right)
$$

Comment: Could you explain the 2nd step? Kinda lost you at the beginning. Also, if there’s another way to solve it, that would be good because I am not quite familiar with the teta sign

Comment: I used the facts that $e^x =1+x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ and $\log(1+x)=x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ for small $x$.

Comment: It seems like the series is bounded above by the series of $1/n^2$, but I have no idea how to prove that because that doesn't seem obvious. I tried a proof by induction but my work just got messy. Also, isn't the index supposed to be $n=1$?

Comment: @Accelerator Thanks for pointing that out (I was barking up the wrong tree until I read your comment).  See my solution for how to prove it.  And yes, I agree that in order to make sense, we need the series to start at $n=1$ instead of $n=0$ (hopefully this is a typo rather than a silly "gotcha" from the problem setter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $(n^{1/n}-1)^2 \geq 0$

Expanding, we have $$n^{2/n} \geq 2n^{1/n} - 1 > 0$$ so that $$n^2 \geq (2\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n.$$

Putting that into your problem, we find $$0 < \frac{(2\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n}{n^4} \leq \frac{n^2}{n^4} = \frac{1}{n^2}$$
and $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, so your series converges by direct comparison.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{\left(2 n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)^n}{n^4} \quad \implies \quad \log(a_n)=n\log \left(2 n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)-4\log(n)$$

Using Taylor expansion
$$\log(a_n)=-2 \log (n)-\frac{\log ^2(n)}{n}+\frac{\log ^3(n)}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{\log ^4(n)}{n^3}\right)$$ Apply it also for $\log(a_{n+1})$ and continue with Taylor expansion
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=-\frac 2n+\frac{(\log (n)-1)^2}{n^2}+\cdots$$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}\sim e^{-\frac 2n}$$